# Issue with xQuartz on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: macos, ssh, mac, macos-catalina, xquartz

I'm getting following error when try to open application 'gmsh' remotely through SSH terminal. How can i fix it ?

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
XRequest.149: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 0x0
XRequest.149: GLXBadContext 0x0
XRequest.149: GLXBadContext 0x0
XRequest.149: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 0xa00006
XRequest.149: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 0xa00006
XRequest.149: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 0xa00006
```

[image]

Comment: You are SSH'ing into the Mac from a remote computer?  And running `gmsh` on that Mac?  What happens if you enter that command directly in that Mac's Terminal?  Also, see this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429760/opengl-rendering-with-x11-forwarding

Comment: @jimtut Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  You should "accept" your own answer, so this question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after running `defaults write org.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true` on local terminal.